# The global element 'XXX' has already been declared

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd2code

I'm using Xsd2Code in order to build classes from the folowing shema:

http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd/ (gmd.xsd)

howewer it keeps throwing the folowing error:

Error: The global element 'http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd:EX_TemporalExtent' has already been declared.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

There are cycles in the include/import/redefine relation, and XSD 1.0 fails to define the rules governing such cycles cleanly enough to guarantee interoperability.  Some tools will have no trouble with such cycles, and others will.